# find the eigenvalues of $5×5$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The product of the non-zero eigenvalues of the matrix is ____.

[image]

---

using characteristic equation , it is too lengthy to find eigenvalues of $5×5$ matrix , I'm looking for any short trick to solve this question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that $(1,0,0,0,1)^T$ and $(0,1,1,1,0)^T$ are eigenvectors by inspection.  What are their corresponding eigenvalues?  (You just need to compute $Av$ for each of the above.)  Now observe that the matrix has only $2$ linearly independent columns, so its kernel has dimension $3$.  Thus $0$ is also an eigenvalue with multiplicity $3$.

Comment: can you give me best link to read eigenvectors by inspection . thanks for hints.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such link.  By "by inspection," I just meant that this matrix is of a particular form so that we figure out the eigenvectors without computation.  Since the first and last columns are the same, multiplying by the column vector $v = (1,0,0,0,1)^T$ yields the sum of these two columns, which is $2v$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be repectively the following matrices:

[image] [image]

Then $A= B +I_5$ where $I_5$ is the identity matrix.

Since B and I commutes then the $eigenvalues(A)=eigenvalues(B) +eigenvalues(I_5)$ (with the same order), that is  $eigenvalue(A)=eigenvalue(B) +1$ (for every eigenvalue of B).

Now commuting the eigenvalues of $B$ is easy since in the first row we have only one nonzero entry.

Comment: @Silence Your welcome

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Note that $\left(\begin{align}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{align}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{align}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ 0\\ -1\end{align}\right)$ are two linearly independent eigenvectors.

Also note that

$\left(\begin{align}0 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ 1\\ 0\end{align}\right),$ $\left(\begin{align}0 \\ -2 \\ 1\\ 1\\ 0\end{align}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{align}0 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ -2\\ 0\end{align}\right)$ are three linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: thanks for hints , please can you hint , how I guess these vectors , thank you.

Comment: Note that $(x,0,0,0,y)$ and $(0,x,y,z,0)$ are invariant subspaces. Thus you can study the eigenvalues of $\left(\begin{matrix}1 &  1\\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 &  1 & 1\\ 1 &  1 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$ separately.